# Plot time series data (wide format)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a merged `dataframe` in R Studio like follows:

```
head(my_df)
     Year        Month.x      val1       Month.y        val2
     2005-01     January     22.43099    January        26.3339814993271
     2005-02     February    26.62969    February       30.8841743766816
     2005-03     March       31.67926    March          27.9245803297443
     2005-04     April       23.65202    April          30.9088206490251
     2005-05     May         25.39969    May            26.494307897712
     2005-06     June        20.30036    June           18.9395527997218
```

The `year` column contains data from January 2005 - December 2015. There was one `"NA"` in `val2` column in data frame but I fixed it with:

```
my_df[is.na(my_df)] <- ""
```

I need to plot this time series data (`val1` and `val2` against `year`) in R. Initially, I am trying to plot `val1` versus `year` using R base graphics:

```
plot(my_df$Year, my_df$val1, type = "b", col = "blue", xlim=c(2005, 2015),
     lwd=1, pch = 1, cex = 0.2, xlab="Year", ylab="Value")
```

but I see a blank graph with this warning.

```
Warning message:
In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can anyone help me to figure out where things are messed up? How can I resolve this problem anyways.

**EDIT1:**

As suggested by @Santosh, `dput(my_df)` is here:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2005-01", "2005-02", "2005-03", "2005-04", 
"2005-05", "2005-06", "2005-07", "2005-08", "2005-09", "2005-10", 
"2005-11", "2005-12", "2006-01", "2006-02", "2006-03", "2006-04", 
"2006-05", "2006-06", "2006-07", "2006-08", "2006-09", "2006-10", 
"2006-11", "2006-12", "2007-01", "2007-02", "2007-03", "2007-04", 
............
"2014-11", "2014-12", "2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04", 
"2015-05", "2015-06", "2015-07", "2015-08", "2015-09", "2015-10", 
"2015-11", "2015-12"),  Month.x = c("January", "February", "March", 
"April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
.............
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December"), val1 = c(22.4309863561828, 
26.629689578869, 31.6792564287634, 23.6520192347222, 25.3996868508065, 
20.3003602638889, 20.2621707795699, 22.3685403172043, 30.7087719888889,
..........
13.8973171652778, 11.3131837150538, 13.2869582405914, 16.4443315347222, 
17.5448029758065, 22.8475848819444, 15.2890522220727), Month.y = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
............
 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
), val2 = c("26.3339814993271", "30.8841743766816", "27.9245803297443", 
"30.9088206490251", "26.494307897712", "18.9395527997218", "21.9441695597826",
..........
"18.3722117002688", "17.8116471652778", "19.684253344086", "25.0107780152778", 
"20.6051117175464")), .Names = c("Year", "Month.x", "val1", 
"Month.y", "val2"), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = "data.frame"
```

**EDIT2:**

Removing `xlim(2005, 2015)` from `plot` function also yields error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: It's probably converting the `""` back to an `NA` which it can't plot. You probably need to impute the missing value, or remove it.

Comment: Maybe you can try `na.rm = TRUE` while plotting. Can you put dput of your input data frame?

Comment: You may also have problem with xlim. Depending on how R sees column one, (char, date, POSIXct) it may not acknowledge  2005, 2015 which are numeric. Make sure that all of the units and structures of the underlying data agree and if you are relying on interpretations that the appropriate packages are loaded. An easy test for this is to remove the xlim and see if it plots (even wrong) and then work on getting the axis and Year column in agreement.

Comment: @Santosh: I tried na.rm=TRUE, but I ended up in another error: na.rm is not a graphical parameter. Please see update for dput().

Comment: @sconfluentus: I tried by removing xlim() but the error persists. Please see the edit.

Comment: @JibranKhan Sorry, I meant before you plot. You transform data frame by just removing NA. That you can do that by `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Yeah that is tough...You will need to address both issues, the NA and the Dates. run `str(my_df$Year)` and see how R views the Year column. From there I can help you get past the xlim issue.

Comment: Here is the str() return: chr [1:132] "2005-01" "2005-02" "2005-03" "2005-04" "2005-05" "2005-06" "2005-07" "2005-08" "2005-09" "2005-10" ...

Comment: @sconfluentus:  As per my understanding, the column year is in Chr format like "2005-01" which seems to be a problem.

Comment: yes...the data is character, the xlim is numeric. The solution below works because the method of transforming with mutate /  gather and Year should reconcile the two.

Comment: Yes, true. The solution below answered the question but I somehow wanted to plot the things using base graphics. How can I work around this problem anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution how you can filter out `NA` cases and plot your data:

1. Select columns you will use
2. Transform `Year` string into a date
3. Transform data from wide to long format
4. Filter out `NA` cases
5. Plot using `ggplot2`

`tidyverse` package loads all the packages you need here (e.g. `dplyr` or `ggplot2`)

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df %>%
    select(Year, val1, val2) %>%
    mutate(Year = as.Date(paste0(Year, "-01"))) %>%
    gather(val, value, -Year) %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, value, color = val)) +
        geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks. What are "val", "value" here? Does it mean "val1", "val2" in my case? I need to keep the missing value of "val2" as BLANK. Somehow, it didn't work for me.

Comment: @JibranKhan I name both `val1` and `val2` as `val`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried. Got this warning: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? and graph look so weird.

Comment: Can you test this with data you provided? Did it still generates error?

Comment: It seems to be working! Let me make some tests. May I know why you didn't use "group=1" in ggplot() ?

Comment: @JibranKhan because when you set `color` ggplot knows that you want at least two separate lines. If there was no color option then I would set group to get two black lines

Comment: Well, thanks. I was trying to plot using base graphics but somehow your suggestion yielded expected result. Two questions: 1) How can I change two lines color since we have have merged them in "val". (2) How can I remove "val" printed with "val1" and "val2" legends?

Comment: @JibranKhan something like this: `scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = c("blue", "red"))`